# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

Any insight as to what may be causing this error? Logcat is below. It was working fine all along and only recently started having this problem. Other searches indicate that it may be related to a lack of resources, or an incorrectly imported package name, but I don't think that is the case. Crashlytics shows that there is plenty of RAM available, and imports haven't changed.

```
       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class <unknown>
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
       at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:19573)
       at com.makerbot.mobile.fragment.printing.status.PrinterLoadingFileFragment.onCreateView(PrinterLoadingFileFragment.java:34)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:447)
       at com.makerbot.mobile.fragment.printing.PrinterStatusViewPagerFragment.updateView(PrinterStatusViewPagerFragment.java:585)
       at com.makerbot.mobile.fragment.printing.PrinterStatusViewPagerFragment.onPrinterStateNotificationReceived(PrinterStatusViewPagerFragment.java:607)
       at com.makerbot.mobile.fragment.printing.PrinterStatusViewPagerFragment$1.onReceive(PrinterStatusViewPagerFragment.java:236)
       at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
       at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
       at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Logcat continued:

```
       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
       at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:19573)
       at com.makerbot.mobile.fragment.printing.status.PrinterLoadingFileFragment.onCreateView(PrinterLoadingFileFragment.java:34)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:447)
       at com.makerbot.mobile.fragment.printing.PrinterStatusViewPagerFragment.updateView(PrinterStatusViewPagerFragment.java:585)
       at com.makerbot.mobile.fragment.printing.PrinterStatusViewPagerFragment.onPrinterStateNotificationReceived(PrinterStatusViewPagerFragment.java:607)
       at com.makerbot.mobile.fragment.printing.PrinterStatusViewPagerFragment$1.onReceive(PrinterStatusViewPagerFragment.java:236)
       at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
       at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
       at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Continued some more:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(BitmapFactory.java)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:516)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:361)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:796)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2004)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:674)
       at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:282)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:896)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:833)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1989)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
       at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:120)
       at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:110)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
       at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:16744)
       at com.makerbot.mobile.fragment.printing.status.PrinterLoadingFileFragment.onCreateView(PrinterLoadingFileFragment.java:34)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:447)
       at com.makerbot.mobile.fragment.printing.PrinterStatusViewPagerFragment.updateView(PrinterStatusViewPagerFragment.java:585)
       at com.makerbot.mobile.fragment.printing.PrinterStatusViewPagerFragment.onPrinterStateNotificationReceived(PrinterStatusViewPagerFragment.java:607)
       at com.makerbot.mobile.fragment.printing.PrinterStatusViewPagerFragment$1.onReceive(PrinterStatusViewPagerFragment.java:236)
       at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
       at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
       at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5171)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

XML Below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:mobile="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/mobile_background_dark"
    >

    <com.makerbot.ui.widget.AspectRatioRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        mobile:aspectRatio="1.3333"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/animationImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/animation_cloudslice"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            />
    </com.makerbot.ui.widget.AspectRatioRelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/printer_status_bar_height"
        >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:progress="33"
            android:max="100"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_printer_slice"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/printer_status_bar_side_padding"
            >
            <com.makerbot.mobile.widget.antenna.AntennaTextView
                android:id="@+id/slice_percent_complete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                mobile:typeface="antenna_black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/printer_status_bar_text_size"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                tools:text="33"/>

            <com.makerbot.mobile.widget.antenna.AntennaTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/slice_percent_complete"
                mobile:typeface="antenna_black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="%"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            >
            <com.makerbot.mobile.widget.antenna.AntennaTextView
                android:id="@+id/status_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                mobile:typeface="antenna_regular"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/loading_print_file"/>

            <com.makerbot.mobile.widget.antenna.AntennaTextView
                android:id="@+id/time_elapsed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                mobile:typeface="antenna_black"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="00:00:00"/>

            <com.makerbot.mobile.widget.antenna.AntennaTextView
                android:id="@+id/time_remaining"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                mobile:typeface="antenna_black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/mobile_text_dark"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/about_remaining"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Corresponding Java file:

```
    package com.makerbot.mobile.fragment.printing.status;

import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.makerbot.api.printing.model.PrinterResponse;
import com.makerbot.api.printing.model.PrinterStateNotification;
import com.makerbot.api.printing.model.PrinterSystemNotification;
import com.makerbot.mobile.R;

/**
 * Created by david on 1/30/15.
 */
public class PrinterLoadingFileFragment extends PrinterStatusFragment {
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView progressTextView;
    private TextView statusTextView;

    public static final String TAG = PrinterLoadingFileFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_printer_status_load_file, null);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.animationImageView);
        ((AnimationDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).start();

        progressBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.slice_percent_complete);
        statusTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPrinterSystemNotificationReceived(PrinterSystemNotification notification) {
        PrinterResponse.Process process = notification.getCurrentProcess();
        if( process == null ) {
            return;
        }
        progressBar.setProgress(Math.round(process.progress));
        progressTextView.setText(Math.round(process.progress)+"");

        if (process.getFilename() != null) {
            statusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.loading_print_file) + " " + process.getFilename().toUpperCase());
        }
    }

    protected void onPrinterStateNotificationReceived(PrinterStateNotification notification) {
        PrinterResponse.Process process = notification.getCurrentProcess();
        if (process == null) {
            return;
        }
        progressBar.setProgress(Math.round(process.progress));
        progressTextView.setText(Math.round(process.progress)+"");

        if (process.getFilename() != null) {
            statusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.loading_print_file) + " " + process.getFilename().toUpperCase());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please post the xml file too..

Comment: Also, there should be more to your stack trace. Both of these messages effectively say "the real cause is deeper in the stack trace, please keep scrolling".

Comment: You are correct. I foolishly did not scroll all the way down in the frame holding the stacktrace. Posted above, along with xml.

Comment: I am guessing that in your java  you are causing a stack overflow, can you post the .java file so we can find it

Comment: posted corresponding java code.

Comment: try **inflater.inflate()** instead of **view.inflate**